# What return type for passing a SwiftUI View?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have objects that build subviews to be used in my app’s main view. I cannot understand what return type I should be using for the methods that build the subviews. I tried various alternatives and got various errors:

- `View` : Use of protocol 'View' as a type must be written 'any View'
- `any View` : Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'
- `some View` : Method does not override any method from its superclass
- `AnyView`: Cannot convert return expression of type 'VStack' to return type 'AnyView'

Here’s the relevant code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let a = A()
        a.getView()
    }
}

class A {
    func getView() -> any View {
        VStack {
            Text("a")
        }
    }
}

class B:A {
    override func getView() -> any View {
        VStack {
            Text("b1")
            Text("b2")
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This kind of design isn't suitable. SwiftUI doesn't really work well with classes and overriding. You should change your design. See [Demystifying SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) for more info.

Comment: @PtitXav Adding `@ViewBuilder` in front of each `getView` declaration and replacing `any` by `some` yields this error: “Method does not override any method from its superclass”

Comment: Sorry. I deleted my comment because it was wrong. The main problem is that e ViewBuilder is not really a function or a var an can not be overridden . It is a kind of struct (see @resultBuilder). SO for your case you should reconsider using class or get another approach for your needs.

Comment: In SwiftUI there should be no objects

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you always get the same signature for the method and this cause a problem. A little cheating trick for your need is to change a little the signature by adding a parameter of current class type:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let a = A()
        let b = B()
        let c = C()
        HStack {
            a.getView(a: a) // shows “A”
            b.getView(a: b) // shows “B1”,“B2”
            c.getView(a: c) // shows “C1”,“C2”,“C3”
            c.getView(a: a) // shows “A”
        }
    }
}

class A {
    func getView(a: A) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text("A")
        }
    }
}

class B:A {
    func getView(a: B) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text("B1")
            Text("B2")
        }
    }
}

class C:A {
    func getView(a: C) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text("C1")
            Text("C2")
            Text("C3")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sweeper notes, this is not a design that is going to work well with SwiftUI. If you find yourself using subclasses, you're probably on the wrong road. It's difficult to know what to advise in this case, because it depends on what you're ultimately trying to do. (In the example you've given, the class isn't necessary at all, so we have to guess what your "real" code is like.)

The tool for doing what you've asked is AnyView, and looks like this:

```
class A {
    func getView() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(
            VStack {
                Text("a")
            }
        )
    }
}

class B:A {
    override func getView() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(
            VStack {
                Text("b1")
                Text("b2")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that AnyView has significant performance penalties, and exists primarily as an escape hatch for when it is impossible to follow usual SwiftUI approaches. But if there is no other design you can use, this is the tool for that.

A somewhat more Swift-like (an particularly SwiftUI-like) way to implement this would be to remove the inheritance and use `@MainActor` view-model classes. Then you can use `some View`, which is preferred. That would look like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let a = A()
        a.getView()
    }
}

@MainActor
class A {
    func getView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text("a")
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class B {
    func getView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text("b1")
            Text("b2")
        }
    }
}
```

A more typical approach would be to turn this around, and pass view model classes (or structs) to Views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        AView(model: A())
    }
}

struct AView: View {
    var model: A
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("a")
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class A {}

struct BView: View {
    var model: B
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("b1")
            Text("b2")
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class B {}
```